# Is there any way to show the name in another row as the new column which is corresponding with the id in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

### I have a csv file read by pandas with the info:

```
Id,  Name,   ManagerId
1.   A.        3
2.   B.        4
3.   C
4.   D
```

---

It means that the manager of A is C (with the Id 3). I want to let pandas understand that. How can I do that? I think I should add a new column "Manager" showing the name of the Manager but I don't know how to do that. Pls help me, thanks so much.

Comment: You can use `map`. If you do something like: df.ManagerId.map(df.set_index('Id').Name)`

Comment: the classic way to do that is to join the table with itself where ManagerId == Id (be careful with the wild dots)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard norms of relational database design here can help think through this problem. You can create a relational database with two dataframes out of your one dataframe.

1. Split the manager details into a new dataframe.

   managers = {'ManagerId':[3,4],'Name':['C','D']}
   managerdf = pd.DataFrame(data = managers)
2. When you want to join the two, join on ManagerId

   df.join(managerdf,rsuffix='Mgmt')

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```
df['Manager'] = df['ManagerId'].map(df.set_index('Id')['Name'])
```